# It won't create role due to insufficient privileges

Tags: sql, oracle

I am student college, and I am trying to finish my project, but I am having issue that it I can't create role.
[Click this image to see it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8mNmv.png)

```
CREATE ROLE pharmacist;
CREATE ROLE administrator;

GRANT SELECT, UPDATE ON Patient TO pharmacist;
GRANT SELECT, UPDATE ON Prescription TO pharmacist;

GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE ON Medication TO administrator;
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE ON pharmacy TO administrator;
GRANT UPDATE ON doctor TO administrator;

GRANT pharmacist TO administrator WITH ADMIN OPTION;

CREATE USER pharmacist_user IDENTIFIED BY pharmacist_password;
GRANT pharmacist TO pharmacist_user;
CREATE USER admin_user IDENTIFIED BY admin_password;
GRANT administrator TO admin_user;
```

I need to know why? and How I can fix it?

I tried to create role and it should be work, but it's not

Comment: And don't tell me that Oracle did not give any error message when you ran that in sqlplus, sqldeveloper or whatever development environment you are using. You should get a message like: ORA-01031: insufficient privileges. That means someone should grant create role to your user.

Answer (score 3):

This failed:

```
CREATE ROLE pharmacist;
```

because of *insufficient privileges*. It means that your user isn't allowed to create roles.

Talk to your DBA (or, if you're the one, connect as a privileged user, such as SYS if you don't have any other) to

```
grant create role to name_of_your_user;
```

Then create a role.

Comment: I did everything, but it's not working, my user is H00426013

Comment: What is "everything"? Oracle is pretty much specific about it: you **do not have privilege to create role**. Until you acquire it, that's it - you can't go any further.